# MVC 5. Generating controls based on data values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic-controls

I have a code for displaing quizes. Quiz have a questions and every question have some options. Problem is in the point that either question and option have their own types:

- question types - radiobutton, checkbox, textarea
- option types - label, textbox(for radiobuttons), textarea(for
  radiobuttons)

So, to display all this stuff in a view I wrote the following code for every question in "for" loop:

```
@if (Model.Questions[i].Type == DAL.Entities.QuestionType.radio)
        {
            <ul class="simple-list">
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                {
                    var option = Model.Questions[i].Options[j];

                    <li>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Questions[i].SelectedOption, option.Id, new { id = option.Id })
                        @if (option.OptionType == OptionType.textbox)
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Questions[i].Options[j].TextAnswer)
                        }
                        else if (option.OptionType == OptionType.textarea)
                        {
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Questions[i].Options[j].TextAnswer)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => option.Name)
                        }

                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].Options[j].TextAnswer)
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
        else if (Model.Questions[i].Type == DAL.Entities.QuestionType.ckeckbox)
        {
            <ul class="simple-list">
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                {
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Questions[i].Options[j].Selected, Model.Questions[i].Options[j].Name)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Questions[i].Options[j].Name)
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Questions[i].TextAnswer)
        }
```

How should I rearrange my code properly to get rid of thats awful condition statements and bring my code into conformity with best practies?

Comment: can anybody help?!